# Is there a way to use loop iteration variables in an area outside the loop?

Tags: python

I want this code to refer to a list with a loop variable inside instead of using the initialised value:

```
i = 1
list = [i,i+1,i+2]
for i in range(3):
  print(list[0])
```

I expected the output to be:

```
0
1
2
```

The output was:

```
1
1
1
```

I have tried `i = None` instead, but an error was (of course) raised.

I have tried using a placeholder inside the loop to refer to:

```
x = 1
list = [x,x+1,x+2]
for i in range(3):
  x = i
  print(list[0])
```

I'm new to Python so I'm not very knowledgeable, hence why I asked. How can I solve this?

Comment: `print(list[i])`

Comment: @flakes the example i've provided has the variable modified. the true case is with lots of different lists to refer to. i think that solution only works in the scenario provided?

Comment: You seem to be thinking that changing the value of `i` will change the value stored at `list[0]`. There is no relation between `list` and `i`; `i` was only used as an *expression* to produce values to put in the list.

Comment: that is correct. how could i make it so the value changes? would i have to redeclare the variable constantly inside the loop?

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Likewise, the value of `x` has nothing to do with the value of `list[0]`. You *evaluated* the expressions `x`, `x+1`, and `x+2` to get `1`, `2`, and `3`; those *values* are stored in the list, not expressions waiting to change as `x` changes.

Comment: @iCxbe please provide the "true case" then, otherwise we cannot help. Maybe also a study of [Python loops tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) can help.

Comment: @Cpt.Hook i'll attempt to minimalise it as best as i can and edit my question.

Comment: You can't make it so the value in the _list_ changes when you change something else later.

Comment: Maybe you want a list of lambda expressions `lambdas= [lambda i=i: i+1 for i in range(3)]`? That's gonna be expensive in the long run, but might be what you want.

Comment: @Cpt.Hook a list of *functions*. Lists contain *objects*. Lambda expressions are not objects, they are syntactical constructs that create function objects.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of your loop you access the same element at index `0`.
To get to each individual element of your list by index you have set it to `i`:

```py
x = 1
lst = [x,x+1,x+2]
for i in range(3):
  print(lst[i])
```

I changed `list` to `lst` as the former is a reserved keyword and shouldn't be used as variable name.

Comment: i appreciate the answer, but it's not quite what i'm looking for. the true case is a lot more complex and cannot be solved by iterating through the list. the point im making is that i need a continuously changing variable that i can call inside a list or another variable.

Comment: So you want the value of the variable store inside a list and then change it via a loop? That won't be possible as you re-assign the value stored in `i` and it is an immutable datatype, so you can't rely on referencing

Comment: it seems i'll have to try that, thank you